# Open - Source Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)

Tags: soap, soa, esb

My situation is that the Microsoft IIS app server and code in C# already exists. 
The Web Services and contracts have been done in the .NET framework. My question is what open source Enterprise Service Bus is available to register the endpoint for sending messages to/from the services on the IIS app server? Can I have a Java-based ESB when my endpoint is written in a different language, C#?

I'm looking for an open-source ESB where I can deploy existing WSDL to register the Microsoft server endpoint and wondering if a Java-based ESB will work? What kind of issues would creep up? Is it better to match endpoint vendor type with esb vendor type?

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody else has chimed in, I guess I'll give it a go.

You'll see that most of the open-source service buses in .NET ([NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus), [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/), etc) stay pretty far away from WSDL - instead preferring to take a more message-centric approach.

- Full disclosure, I'm deeply involved with NServiceBus.

Java-based ESBs tend to be more open to integrating more web-service-centric approaches.

The tradeoffs associated with introducing non-Microsoft technology in your production environment center around your operations team's familiarity with them. There's also the development side of things, but in my experience, that tends to be more minor in comparison.

Hope that helps in some small way.

Comment: If an ESB is about integration how is staying away from a WSDL helping integration. That comment makes no sense.

Comment: The Bus Architectural Style is about allowing independent evolution of event sources and sinks, not about integrating pre-existing systems. The Broker Architectural Style is about integrating systems - especially those that aren't really expected to change much. The open-source service buses in .net follow the bus style as described here. Java-centric ESBs tend to follow the broker style. It's the problem of marketing getting intermingled with architecture that confuses things.

Answer (score 3):

Warewolf ESB is a GPL Licensed Open Source ESB based on the Microsoft Stack. You can download an installer from http://warewolf.io, or the source code from Github at https://github.com/Warewolf-ESB/Warewolf-ESB

Its very easy to work with, and is highly extensible. The development team are also very friendly and are quick to respond to the communities queries.